# What is the difference between PEAR and Composer?

Tags: php, package, composer-php, pear

[PEAR](http://pear.php.net/) is used to install a PHP software package and [Composer](http://getcomposer.org) is used for the same thing. I believe Composer handles dependencies better but is that the only difference? Can anybody explain the difference between these two package managers and tell me when to use which?

Comment: a shame that this question is closed.

Comment: @Adam Already three years old however I voted to reopen. It is a good question. For others to stumble upon it you might consider to reopen this question, too.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It might be a bit soon to regard PEAR as deprecated but I don't believe it will take long before it is. Composer is thriving and mature with a lot of packages and and active development. Therefore it might be better to use Composer as [the standard for package](http://www.phptherightway.com/#dependency_management) management tool in PHP.

Using PEAR is more cumbersome for package maintainers. Therefore a lot of the code on PEAR is outdated. A developer needs to get it packages 'PEAR-reviewed' before it might get published on PEAR, so few packages are available compared to the number of packages [available in Composer](https://packagist.org/). Also, there is no way to install a package in PEAR for one single project. All packages are installed globally. With Composer you can install packages one a per-project basis *or* globally. Well and then there is the lack of dependency management in PEAR, which frankly should be the one thing a package manager does well.

One thing you *can* do with PEAR and not with Composer is installing [PECL extensions](http://pecl.php.net/). There is however [pickle](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/pickle) which uses Composer and lets you define native PHP extentions dependencies in your `composer.json` file. The pickle project is momentarily undergoing quite some development and should not yet be considered mature.

[This blog post](http://fabien.potencier.org/the-rise-of-composer-and-the-fall-of-pear.html) by Fabien Potencier might be a bit opinionated, but I think it is quite right. If you have an option, choose Composer so PEAR can die in peace. Even when you [ask the PEAR maintainers](http://php-pear.1086190.n5.nabble.com/Questions-about-PEAR-amp-Composer-td36854.html) most will tell you that Composer is the way forward, although some might still have their hopes for [Pyrus](https://github.com/pyrus/Pyrus). (This was intended to be PEAR improved, but got kindof buried under the exploding popularity of Composer.)

By the way, you can use Composer to install PEAR packages as well, see [the Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#pear).

<sub>**See also:**

[1] [Informative slide deck about PHP package management](http://sequoia.makes.software/composer-talk/#/)</sub>

Comment: Nowadays, many PEAR packages are available on composer via [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/pear/) (official repo).

Comment: Is `pecl` still used? I installed `xdebug` and had the option between `pecl` and `apt` on debian. Guess what I used.