# Difference between composer and pear

Tags: composer-php, pear

What is the basic difference between composer and pear. On pear official site it is stated that now people are shifting towards composer but I read on this site that composer is packager and pear is dependency manager.

Answer (score 1):

This website seems to answer your question rather clearly:

https://williamjxj.wordpress.com/2014/02/22/php-pear-and-composer-2/

It says that PEAR is a package manager for the whole system, whereas Composer is a dependency manager for individual projects and doesn't install anything globally but only locally for individual projects.

This has actually been asked before, it was also answered very well. Here is the question: [What is the difference between PEAR and Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199824/what-is-the-difference-between-pear-and-composer?rq=1)